# Should I still care about Android version 2.x?

Tags: android

New devices support at least Android 4.0 and many people started to change their phones. Do you still think that we should target Android version 2.x?

*I ask this because it won't be that easy for me to support 2.x because of my native libraries. I also have to buy Android 2.2 froyo device for my tests. So, I am trying to find out if all of the effort is feasible or not.*

Comment: Android 2.3.3 is still at ~30% but it is declining. If your app is going to be released soon that I would try support 2.3.3 if it's not too complicated. If it is then I'd go straight to 4.0. No reason to invest too much in a rapidly declining version.

Comment: If you want that your app is used by almost all android device then you must target version 2.x .

Comment: There's still a lot of new devices being sold with 2.3.x. They're mostly cheaper/entry-level devices. 2.3.x runs well on lower-spec hardware while 4.x doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gingerbread 2.3.3 is on [1/3 of active android devices](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html) so I think it is something to care about.

Comment: I have purchased the device, published the app and saw that 1/3 myself too.

Answer (score 1):

I've has same issue too. Resolved restricting some functionality like above:

```
int sdkversion = 6; //or whatever
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT<sdkversion){
        ...DO NOTHING ABOUT THAT FUNCTIONALITY...
    } else {
        ...DO IT...
    }
```

Comment: In my opinion, that's not really supporting lower SDK versions.

Comment: Yes it is. For example i use `linearlayout.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(image));` that is supported from SDK 16, so i put that code inside the if..else and set minsdk to 11!

Comment: Supporting lower SKD versions would be, if you implement the selected functionality even for older sdks.

Comment: This would be enough. In my case, I have to compile my c&c++ libraries for armv6 and armv7. That is the time consuming part.. After that, I could use your comparison to load the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

This should help you out :) I always check it out before embarking on a new idea.

http://www.appbrain.com/stats/top-android-sdk-versions

As for your native libraries, there are plenty of apps out there that only support 4.x versions and still do very well. There are some really decent devices that run gingerbread (2.3 I believe) and are perfectly suitable to all recent apps, but due to manufacturers wont be receiving an update.

Of course, various folk root their phones and use custom roms, so maybe it's not that bad afterall. These stats, can't take that into account, obviously.

HTH.